# How to obtain an InputStream when opening an IgnitePath (returns HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemPositionedReadable)?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ignite, distributed-filesystem

Usually, when working with Hadoop and Flink, opening/reading a file from a distributed file system will return a Source (counterpart of Sink) object extending the java.io.InputStream.

However, in Apache Ignite, the IgfsSecondaryFileSystem, and more specifically the IgniteHadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystem, returns an object of type HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemPositionedReadable when calling their "**open**" method (by passing an IgfsPath).

**HadoopIgfsSecondaryFileSystemPositionedReadable** offers a "**read**" method but requires to know details on where the data, which is intended to be read, is located, such as the input stream position.

```
/**
 * Read up to the specified number of bytes, from a given position within a file, and return the number of bytes
 * read.
 *
 * @param pos Position in the input stream to seek.
 * @param buf Buffer into which data is read.
 * @param off Offset in the buffer from which stream data should be written.
 * @param len The number of bytes to read.
 * @return Total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data (EOF).
 * @throws IOException In case of any exception.
 */
public int read(long pos, byte[] buf, int off, int len) throws IOException;
```

How to determine these details before calling the **read** method?

I am quite new to these frameworks and maybe there exists a different way to obtain an InputStream based on an IgfsPath pointing to a file stored in a Hadoop file system?

I am trying to achieve what is described here: https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/secondary-file-system

Thanks in advance for any hint !

Answer (score 0):

[IgfsSecondaryFileSystem](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/igfs/secondary/IgfsSecondaryFileSystem.html) interface is not supposed to be used directly. You can configure your Hadoop cluster to be used as a secondary FS for read-through and write-through operations.

[IgfsSecondaryFileSystem](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/igfs/secondary/IgfsSecondaryFileSystem.html) should only be specified in configuration as [FileSystemConfiguration#secondaryFileSystem](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/FileSystemConfiguration.html#setSecondaryFileSystem-org.apache.ignite.igfs.secondary.IgfsSecondaryFileSystem-) property.

You should use [IgniteFileSystem](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteFileSystem.html) interface instead. You can get an instance of it by calling [Ignite#fileSystem(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#fileSystem-java.lang.String-) method. To acquire an `InputStream` by IGFS path, you can use [IgniteFileSystem#open(...)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteFileSystem.html#open-org.apache.ignite.igfs.IgfsPath-) method.